# Login to liferay using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, liferay, liferay-7

After lot of problems i finally got liferay sign in through jmeter work. But it only worked twice. First with one user in the thread group. And then i used 10 users out of which 3 were successfully logged in. So it means my way of doing it has no problem (since it was successful on 4 occasions). But next time onward, it stopped working. Only suspicious observation I have is all the requests are getting same auth token (p_auth) no matter how many times or how many users i run it with. I even restarted jmeter. Why would it generate the same token consistently for all different requests through jmeter? When i try a browser, it works (comes with different token every time).

How do I get it to working? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd guess that all these requests use the same session cookie. Did you check that your _HTTP Cookie Manager_ is sitting at the correct position?

Comment: I had the dev team disable the authentication and it worked. Now it ignores the auth token though all the requests use the same token.

Answer (score 3):

Liferay introduces a token (p_auth) for CSRF protection. This token can be used just once, and that's a problem for performance tests. 
You should disable that token during the tests execution, but remember to enable it again after the tests.

```
auth.token.check.enabled=false
```